# Displaying data on android layout as .Net GridView

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I need to display data on the table (like as .Net GridView). I've used ListView , but it doesn't seem as I want. For instance,  headers and columns are not on the alignment. I retrieve data from web service, it contains sql tables.

How can I display the data as .Net GridView design and how can I retrieve selected item's columns values.

Comment: Please take a look at this post http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/

Answer (score 0):

Android has it's own [GridView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html). It's similar to a ListView, so if you've worked with a ListView, then a GridView should be okay.

Here's a [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/).